# Polymer - How to slowly migrate from HTML imports to ES6 modules?

Tags: es6-modules, html-imports, polymer-3.x

As said in the [Polymer-Summit 2017](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-08-23-hands-on-30-preview), web-components, in Polymer 3.0, won't be imported using HTML-imports but ES6-modules.

So I am looking for a way to change all my HTML-imports one by one into ES6-module's `import` without making unstable code.

For exemple:
Here's [a little simple project](http://plnkr.co/edit/JHzRq6Ys5UCA08J5HOnu?p=preview).
Their are 3 files:

```
|-index.html
|-custom-element.html
|-MyModule.html
```

The `index.html` imports the `custom-element`component and instantiate one in the DOM.
The `custom-element.html` imports `MyModule.html`, and use its function `square(number)`.
All imports are made using HTML-imports.
I am trying to figure out how to make just `MyModule` an ES6-module and then import it in the `custom-element.html` file without breaking the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the script tag's type into `<script type="module">`.

Import the ES6 module from inside the script module.

[Here's the plunker with the full solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/F7KdBqxe0WRMKet74kvt?p=preview).

Comment: Your plunker has an HTML import and doesn't have a script with type="module"...Am I missing something?

Comment: The script inside the custom-element file.